# How many repeatition there are in spriterenderer in adaptative tilemode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Unity recently added a new functionnality on SpriteRenderer in order to use tile system.
When I set SpriteRenderer with these:

- Draw mode: Tiled
- Tile mode: Adaptative

I can't find a correct way to know how many time the central part of my sprite is repeated in x and y axis.

With image:
Using this [sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPTHS.png)
I want to know how many times in my sprite renderer the zone "E" is repeated
[like in this exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dKr3.png)

SpriteRenderer.adaptiveModeThreshold is an important value to take into account in the process. 
From the documentation of Unity:

> Stretch Value:
>   Use the Stretch Value slider to set the value between 0
>   and 1. Note that 1 represents an image resized to twice its original
>   dimensions, so if the Stretch Value is set at 1, the section repeats
>   when the image is stretched to twice its original size.

documentation links: [SpriteRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html), [adaptiveModeThreshold](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-adaptiveModeThreshold.html), [9slice sprites](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/9SliceSprites.html)

Thank you for your time!

My best try so far is:

```
SpriteRenderer sr = bc.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
Sprite s = sr.sprite;

// retrieve data of sprite
float szTopBorder, szBottomBorder, szLeftBorder, szRightBorder; // sz of borders (in meter)
Rect innerRect; // the center rect of the spriterenderer without borders (in meter)
FoundInnerTilledRect(sr, out szTopBorder, out szBottomBorder, out szLeftBorder, out szRightBorder, out innerRect);

// the center size of sprite without border (in meter)
Vector2 sz = s.textureRect.size / s.pixelsPerUnit;
sz.x -= szLeftBorder + szRightBorder;
sz.y -= szBottomBorder + szTopBorder;

// Compute how many time the tile can repeat in "continuous" mode
float countX = (innerRect.size.x / sz.x);
float countY = (innerRect.size.y / sz.y);

if (sr.tileMode == SpriteTileMode.Adaptive)
{
    // Compute how many time the tile can repeat in "adaptative" mode
    countX = Mathf.Ceil(countX - sr.adaptiveModeThreshold);
    countY = Mathf.Ceil(countY - sr.adaptiveModeThreshold);
}
```

Here the code of FoundInnerTilledRect()

```
public static void FoundInnerTilledRect(SpriteRenderer sr, out float szTopBorder, out float szBottomBorder, out float szLeftBorder, out float szRightBorder, out Rect innerRect)
{
    var s = sr.sprite;

    float szX = sr.size.x;
    float szY = sr.size.y;

    szTopBorder = s.border.w / s.pixelsPerUnit;
    szBottomBorder = s.border.y / s.pixelsPerUnit;
    szLeftBorder = s.border.x / s.pixelsPerUnit;
    szRightBorder = s.border.z / s.pixelsPerUnit;
    innerRect = new Rect();
    innerRect.xMin = szLeftBorder;
    innerRect.xMax = szX - szRightBorder;
    innerRect.yMin = szBottomBorder;
    innerRect.yMax = szY - szTopBorder;

    // set correct center for the rect
    innerRect.center = - new Vector2((szRightBorder - szLeftBorder), (szTopBorder - szBottomBorder)) * 0.5f;
}
```